# Old visa and new visa

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-expiration

I have an old schengen visa that expires on the 11th and a new one that starts on the 12th and is valid for three months.
Is it possible to arrive on 9th?

Comment: Assuming that the one that expires on the 11th is valid on the 9th, you could. But how long are you planning to stay?

Comment: I will be staying for a month

Answer (score 0):

The validity of your visas covers a continuous time period, so you can remain in the Schengen area beyond the expiration of the first visa, because the second visa will then be in effect.

You may need to point out both visas to airline check-in staff or immigration officers.